# MySQL query; if greater than a value 'yes' else 'no'; grouping

Tags: mysql, filter

I have this data in a table:

```
id  account status
1      8       1
2      8       4
4      8       3
5      8       1
6      1       4
7      1       3
```

I want a single query to return me the account number, and if any of the status' for that account is **<3** then return 'Yes' else 'No'. So, these results:

```
account pending
8          'Yes'
1          'No'
```

I had:

`SELECT account, IF(status>2,'No','Yes') as pending FROM table GROUP BY account;`

But it only seems to take into account the first row for each account. (ex. id 1's status=1 so even if id 4's status is changed so status=1, it'll still think all is greater than 2.)

I really appreciate any help. I normally can do decent query design, but this is giving me a brain cramp. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
    SELECT account, IF(max(status)>2,'No','Yes') as pending 
FROM table 
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: Entirely correct, thanks! I realize I stated my question wrong, I meant if ANY of the status is <3 return 'yes', else 'no'. Using MIN did what I needed.Geez, how could I forget MIN()/MAX()..  Long Friday. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or), for example BIT_OR:

```
SELECT account, IF(BIT_OR(status>2),'No','Yes') as pending FROM table GROUP BY account;
```